# How to make the following data separable for the classification into three classes?

Tags: machine-learning

[image]The figure below shows the PCA projections of inputs which are 14 meteorological features, (i.e. wind, temperature, humidity, pressure, and so on.)
I would like to use any technique to make it more separable than this, The ISOMAP method is also used instead of PCA, but it gave a non-separable distribution as well! Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: have you considered trying to use an autoencoder?

Comment: Excuse my naivety...but what is an autoencoder?

Comment: An autoencoder is a nonlinear approach to dimensionality reduction. It's an unsupervised learning technique that can, in its simplest form, just be a feed forward neural network formed a certain way. I would recommend googling it.

Comment: Thanks choward for your swift response and clarification.... I hope autoencoder would be better than what isomap was....

Comment: The point of these methods is to make data more separable, conditional on the fact they can be separated. I don't know much about ISOMAP, but I know an autoencoder can fair well for these types of tasks. Hopefully your data can actually be separated like you wish.

Comment: I really appreciate your clarification and suggestion, thanks choward

Comment: Is this data set public so one could try to make it more separable?

Comment: No this data set is not public, but it's similar to any kind of other metrological data  (wind speed, temperature, pressure, humidity, and so on) for the complete year with an hourly resolution.